# What is the process of going to the reception at a hospital and telling them you've arrived called?

Tags: word-choice

Like, how would you put it in this sentence?

"I've gone to the doctor's office and ____"?

Comment: You’ve checked in.

Comment: Many ways of filling it (Depending on which country) : "registered myself" + "taken a token" + "booked an appointment" + "reserved a slot" + "informed the receptionist" + Etc. (Assuming you are here for treatment, not for repairing some equipment or for selling medicines : in this case there will be other ways of filling it)

Comment: In the US you've definitely "checked in".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase most often used to describe the process of announcing one's arrival to reception is "check-in".